# How to use jbuild and ppx_driver with ppx_deriving

Tags: ocaml, ppx

I am trying to use  [jbuilder](https://github.com/janestreet/jbuilder/) together with [ppx_deriving](https://github.com/whitequark/ppx_deriving) (`ppx_deriving_yojson` specifically) but got stuck for well over an hour now. My current approach is a `jbuild` file, containing the following:

```
(jbuild_version 1)
(executables
((names (my-binary))
(libraries
 (ppx_deriving
  ppx_deriving_yojson
  cohttp
  yojson))
(preprocess (pps (ppx_deriving_yojson ppx_driver.runner)))))
```

But that results in

```
Command [5] exited with code 1:
$ (cd _build/default && ../.ppx/default/ppx_deriving_yojson+ppx_driver.runner/ppx.exe --dump-ast -o src/my_file.pp.ml --impl src/my_file.ml)
File "src/my_file.ml", line 16, characters 5-13:
Error: Attribute `deriving' was not used
```

Running the generated `ppx_driver` in `_build/.ppx/default/ppx_deriving_yojson+ppx_driver.runner/ppx.exe` manually with `-print-transformations` gives empty output, so I am obviously missing something.

The code builds fine with `topkg` by just including `ppx_deriving` and `ppx_deriving_yojson` as dependencies.

Comment: What version of ppx_deriving + ppx_deriving_yojson are you using?  jbuilder will only work with ppxs based on ocaml-migrate-parsetree and there hasn't been a release to opam of ppx_deriving based on ocaml-migrate-parsetree yet.

Answer (score 2):

As of more recent versions of ppx_deriving_yojson this should be possible.

Code:

```
type t = {x: int; y: int} [@@deriving to_yojson]

let () = print_endline (Yojson.Safe.to_string (to_yojson {x= 1; y= 2}))
```

And a sample `jbuild` file:

```
(jbuild_version 1)

(executables
 ((names (main))
  (preprocess (pps (ppx_deriving_yojson)))
  (libraries (ppx_deriving_yojson.runtime))))

(install
 ((section bin)
  (files ((main.exe as main)))))
```